# what OpenCv Image type is CV_8SC3

Tags: image, types, opencv

Until now I had only encountered this kind of types for a `cv::Mat`:

`CV_<bit_depth>(U|F)C<number_of_channels>` with U standing for unsigned and f for float.

So in `CV_8SC3`:

8 -> stands for bit depth

C3 -> stands for three channels

But what does S stand for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` means "signed"

So `8S` is mapped to C++ `signed char` data type